# How to set cookie and based on if cookie exists skipping login screen?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, cookies

I need to create a webpage that on first visiting it asks you to put just your name, then once they click login my jQuery will slide away that panel and they will be in the main part of the website. The next time they visit the web page it will go straight to the "main part" rather than ask their name again.

I've never made cookies before how, possible is this?

Also I've created my login form but when i click my submit button it refreshes the page, i want the submit button to be the thing that activates the jQuery.

```
<div class="login-page">
   <div class="form">
    <form class="login-form" method="POST" action="">

   <!-- user inputs -->
   <p class="name">Name:</p><input type="text" name="username" placeholder="Enter Your name Here" />

   <!-- your submit button -->
   <input class="login" type="submit" name="submit" value="login">

</div>

</div>
```

I need it to be an input form because that data is going to be saved onto a database by someone else.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In JS, creating a cookie is as simple as `document.cookie = "username=John Doe";`
And then reading cookies is `var cookies = document.cookie;` which will give you a semi-colon delimited string of cookies.

As for the second problem, you are using an HTML submit button, which submits the HTML Form. You have to instead capture the click event and prevent the default action. Something like this:

```
$('.login').click(function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    //Do more stuff
})
```